# Sort dates in an array from earliest to latest in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to sort dates in an array from earliest to newest in JavaScript? `dateArray.sort()` doesn't seem to be working at all.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var dateArray = new Array();
for(i=0;i<timelineItemCount;i++)
{
    var today = new Date();
    var randomDates = randomDate(today, new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+7));
    dateArray.push(randomDates);
}   
dateArray.sort();
console.log(dateArray);

function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Use a numeric sort (instead of the default string comparison function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date object has comparisons built in, you just have to tell it what to do.

```
dateArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (a > b) - (a < b);
});
```

Comment: what does `a>b` and `a<b` achieve that just taking the difference between the two dates doesn't?

Comment: @MattBurland See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886446/problem-trying-to-use-the-c-qsort-function/3886497#3886497 , the language is C, but the considerations still apply.

Comment: Fair enough, but since we are dealing with integers and the range isn't wide enough to overflow (even `new Date(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 2)` is sometime in the year `144683`), it's probably not a great concern here.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in your own comparison function to `sort`:

```
dateArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Also note the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) page on `.sort`:

> **compareFunction**
>
> Optional. Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to *each character's Unicode code point value*, according to the string conversion of each element.

By default you are sorting the dates alphabetically by the result of their `toString()` method, which is probably alphabetically by day of the week.