# How to sort an array in ascending order in C?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program which prompts the user to say how many elements an array should have, then fill that array with numbers:

```
    int n;
    int i;
    float numbers[100];

    printf("Enter number of elements:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        scanf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);
```

I'm trying to write a function which takes that array of numbers, and sorts it in ascending order.
I read somewhere online that there's actually a built in function in C that does this - qsort(). Here's my code:

```
void sort(int n, float array[])
{
    int i;
    int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        return(*(int*)a - *(int*)b );
    }

    qsort(array, n, sizeof(float), cmpfunc);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        printf("%.2f\n", array[i]);
}
```

Basically the problem is I don't think I'm implementing the function correctly. For example, I'll run the program, set the array size to 5, and input the following numbers:

> 1,9,2,8,5

The output I get is:

> 1,2,8,9,0

There is a similar pattern in all my outputs.

It sorts it somewhat decently, except it always ends with a 0, and for some unknown reason, randomly skips one number of the array and doesn't sort it (in the example above 5 is skipped). In the for loop, I had i set to 0, but then my output would also skip a number when sorting, and it would still have a 0, except this time it would be at the beginning of the output.

Finally, it should be noted that I have absolutely no idea how the qsort() function works, or why it needs that other compare function to work, I just sort of copy pasted it in there.

If anyone knows the answer to my problem please help me out I'd really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Functions cannot be nested in C. And `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` looks like an off-by-one.

Comment: You are sorting an array of `float`, so the pointers passed to the comparison function point to `float` values, not `int` values.

Comment: Casting pointers pointing at `float` to `int*` doesn't look like a good idea.

Comment: @wildplasser Functions can be nested in GCC extension.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)` should be `for(i = 0; i < n ; i++)`, and `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)` should be `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT They can, but they really shouldn't. This is just plain *weird*. It's a bad habit to get into because it's extremely non-portable and the alternative is really quite simple.

Comment: @tadman: It is not weird; nested functions were developed for a reason. People did not just put considerable effort into writing and supporting them for no reason. Saying it is a bad habit because it is non-portable is assuming that portability is an all-encompassing goal. It is not. Some people, or people working on some projects, do not develop for portability; they develop to solve particular problems they have, and the values and issues they are dealing with may favor using extensions over portability. And the alternative is not simple if the lexical scoping provided is desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If a given project lives in a GCC-only world *and* that sort of thing is necessary, then sure, but that sounds like a tiny, tiny minority of all use cases. GCC has implemented a lot of things just because someone thought it'd be neat, not necessarily because it was a good idea. In some cases that lead to introducing new behaviour that caught on, and in other cases it's an evolutionary dead-end. I think in this case the non-nested version makes more sense, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not filling the last element of your array here

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    scanf("%f\n", &numbers[i]);
```

And in the sorting function you are: not printing the first element; printing the last element, which can be anything; printing an element out of the array's bounds

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    printf("%.2f\n", array[i]);
```

Both the loops should be

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

And it seems that using `qsort` with a `float` array isn't straightforward, you should adjust its comparison function as said here: [Problem trying to use the C qsort function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3886446/3422102)

Comment: This answer misses the fact that `float*` values are cast as `int*` and dereferenced inside the `cmpfunc`, which invokes undefined behavior

Comment: If I switch the for loop used for filling the array, I end up getting prompted one additional time for an extra element. (i.e. if I specify I want 5 elements, I get prompted for 6 elements). Any idea what this is?

Comment: @Wacy if you enter 5 the first time, then you are asked to enter 5 elements

Comment: Using `qsort` with a `float` array should be OK. The comparision function is wrong. The linked question is also saying so.

Comment: Yes I updated the answer to reflect the content of the link

Comment: I have updated the link formatting. If you use `[title](linkaddress)` it will format correctly. If you go to the question and right-click on `"share"` and copy-url, you will get the StackOverflow short-url for use in your answer.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for that! I will remember for the next times

Answer (score 2):

OP's compare fails when

`a, b` not within about rage of `int`.

`a, b` unequal, but `(int) a == (int) b`

The subtraction overflows.

---

A better compare

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
  float fa = *(const float *)a;
  float fb = *(const float *)b;
  return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}
```

---

Use `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` as well answered by [@Davide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485721/2410359).

---

Fails then `n > 100`.